# move between tabs in firefox on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, firefox

In Windows, I was able to move between firefox tabs by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1,2,...,9</kbd>. But in latest version in mint, I can only move to next and back by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I fix it?

Comment: With Ctrl+PageDown, you can at least also go backwards, .no need to cycle through all your tabs if you missed the one you wanted. (Ctrl+PageUp == Ctrl+Tab)

Comment: @Anthon: Yes, but going to first tab, when I'm on 5 of 10 tabs, is really difficult!

Comment: You can use Alt+<1-9>. Firefox versions for Linux and Windows are different here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jimmij commented, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1,2,3....9</kbd> to switch between TABs on the Linux version of Firefox.